# video recording distorts vertical lines

Tags: video, bugs

Here's a problem I've noticed on all Android, from old 2.2 to the new demo tablets at the store:

When in camera video mode, record a column or a pillar, and slightly rotate the device back and forth left/right. Notice that the column appears to be changing shape, wobbling.

I remember seeing in consumer-reports or similar magazine that most Android phones have worse video quality, I think only G2 had a very good rating.

I wonder if there is any known fix for this problem? Which models don't have this bug?

Comment: That's a common distortion associated with wide-angle lenses.  In order to get in a lot of the scene into the shot, the angle of view for the lens is widened.  If it wasn't widened like that, you'd have to step back about 5-7 paces to get the same shotIt creates the same distortion as [fish-eye lenses do](https://www.google.com/search?q=fish+eye&tbm=isch).  Then, so your shot doesn't look like a circle, the image is distorted to fit into the rectangle frame so common to photos.

Comment: @KevinOrr Thanks, but are you sure this is what's happening here? I never enabled wide-angle-lense mode, and if anything I think the problem with phones is that they don't zoom in enough, not that the angle wasn't wide enough. Do you know if there is any hidden setting that could turn this feature off?